# ¿Cómo leer un Excel que contenga una estructura de categorías y sub-categorías?

Tags: c#, excel, genexus

Necesito recorrer un Excel que sirve para armar un árbol de categorías para un sitio web, que debe ser intuitivo para que los clientes lo entiendan.

Me es difícil descifrar la lógica para poder leerlo y guardar correctamente las categorías, cada una con su categoría padre si es que tiene, o si corresponde a una categoría de último nivel, es decir, categoría donde el usuario va a poder hacer clic y se cargará un catálogo de artículos correspondiente.

El Excel se divide en niveles y categorías, donde cada fila es una categoría y cada columna es el nivel donde está la categoría, les pongo el siguiente ejemplo.

[image: Ejemplo de carga del Excel]

Como ven tengo Nivel 1, 2 y 3. Esto lo hice para que en cada fila solo haya una categoría, así el ID de la categoría corresponde con el número de fila.
La primer categoría "Destacados" está ubicada en el nivel uno, por lo tanto no puede tener una Categoría Padre, y en este caso, tampoco posee una Sub-categoría en la posición (fila+1,columna+1), por lo que es una categoría último nivel.

En cambio, la categoría "Bocallave", si posee una Sub-Categoría en la posición (fila+1,columna+1), por lo tanto no es una categoría de último nivel, y es categoría padre de "Juegos de bocallave" y esta última si es una de último nivel, luego la siguiente categoría "Bocallaves 1/4", posee una sub-categoría llamada "Accesorios", de la cual es padre, esta misma tiene como padre a "Bocallaves".

Espero que así se logre entender como es que deseo leer este Excel.
Ahora mismo estoy programando en Genexus, y el código que tengo es el siguiente, que está obviamente incompleto, pero podrán ver que es lo que quise hacer.

```
&ExcelDocument.SelectSheet('Categorias')
            &CantNiveles = 3
                for &i = 2 to 100000 step 1
                    for &j = 1 to &CantNiveles
                        if not &ExcelDocument.Cells(&i,&j).Value.IsEmpty()
                            if &j = 1 
                                &Categoria.CategoriaId = &i
                                &Categoria.CategoriaNombre = &ExcelDocument.Cells(&i,&j).Text
                                &Categoria.CategoriaPadreId.SetNull()
                                if &ExcelDocument.Cells(&i+1,&j+1).Value.IsEmpty()
                                    &Categoria.CategoriaUltimoNivel = 1
                                else
                                    &Categoria.CategoriaUltimoNivel = 0
                                endif
                            else
                                &Categoria.CategoriaId = &i
                                &Categoria.CategoriaNombre = &ExcelDocument.Cells(&i,&j).Text
                            endif
                        else
                            
                        endif
                    endfor
                endfor
```

El objeto `&Categoria` es como una clase en c#, así que si alguien podría resolverlo en c# no habría ninguna diferencia ya que puedo traducirlo fácilmente a Genexus.

Adjunto enlace del archivo Excel por si alguien lo necesita, y además hay un ejemplo visual de cómo debería ser el menú final: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H34q9CAh9BVVBeZlLhCGIA0krp35tZIn/view?usp=sharing

Se pueden añadir las variables que crean necesarias.

Si hace falta información no duden en dejarme un comentario.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda!!

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo la librería de ExcelDataReader te dejo el enlace para que cheques la documentación.

https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader

Es muy buena y te ahorras la lectura, solo te enfocas en ver tus campos vacíos dentro del arreglo que te genera.